# Adding several data on a specific column on a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a table that can store a "Training Information" data. The code below is working (see sample result below) however, it can only add one data at a time.

[image]

What I would like to happen is to be able to add several data on my "Attendees" column only, while the other columns will contain the same data since it is the same training.

Any ideas?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lr As ListRow
Set ws = Sheets("Trainings")
ws.Unprotect "321321"
Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add
lr.Range(1, 1).Value = UCase(title.Value)
lr.Range(1, 2).Value = UCase(Date.Value)
lr.Range(1, 3).Value = UCase(Venue.Value)
lr.Range(1, 4).Value = UCase(VenueAdd.Value)
lr.Range(1, 5).Value = UCase(Attendees.Value)
```

Comment: So what is wrong with your code? Any errors? If so which and where?  What does your code vs. what did you expect from your code? Please also show the definitions of your variables, it's unclear what `title.Value` is because `title` is not declared. Also don't use `Date` as variable name it is already a reserved key word of VBA.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ There are no errors. However, I do not know how to code adding multiple names on the column "Attendees" from my form. title.value is a textbox from my form which is user defined. I'm thinking using a listbox to gather the data for my "Attendees" column, however I do not know how I can transfer it while at the same time populating the other columns with the same data.

Comment: I don't see the problem. You fill your 5 text boxes with data and press the "insert" button that runs the code above. Then you change the name of the attendee and press the insert button again. This should add the another line with the same data but a different attendee. (to be continued …).